# Python: Writing Counter to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, counter

I have a csv file of data that has the columns `‘number’`, `’colour’`, `’number2’`, `’foo’`, `’bar’`, which looks like:

```
12, red, 124, a, 15p
14, blue, 353, c, 7g
12, blue, 125, d, 65h
12, red, 124, c, 12d
```

I want to count the number of times number, colour and number2 occur together, so for example, the output from the above list would be: `’12, red, 124 :2’,’14, blue, 353: 1’, ’12, blue, 125: 1’`. I’ve done this by using:

```
import csv
datafile=open('myfile.csv','r')
usefuldata=[] 
for line in datafile: 
    usefuldata.append(line) 
from collections import Counter
outfile1=Counter((line[1],line[2],line[3]) for line in usefuldata)  
print(outfile1)
```

This gives me :

```
Counter({(‘12’,’red’,’135’): 21, (‘15’,’blue’,’152’):18, (‘34’,’green’,’123’):16 etc})
```

Which is great, but I’d like to write this out to a file. I'd like the file to have 4 columns: number, colour, number2, and count. I realise this is a common question and I’ve tried a few different approaches suggested on other threads, but none have worked.

```
Newfile=open(‘newfile.csv’,’wb’)
fieldnames=['a','b']
csvwriter=csv.DictWriter(newfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
csvwriter.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in fieldnames))
for row in outfile1:
    csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

And

```
with open('newfile.csv','wb') as csvfile:
    fieldnames=['number','colour','number2']
    writer=csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(Counter((line[1],line[2],line[3]) for line in usefuldata))
    countwriter=csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=', ')
    countwriter.writerow(outfile1)
```

Both give me the error

```
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I've also tried using pickle:

```
import pickle
with open('newfile.csv','wb') as outputfile:
    pickle.dump(outfile1, outputfile)
```

gives me gibberish files.

My current attempt is to use

```
writer=csv.DictWriter(newfile, outfile1)
for line in outfile1:
    writer.writerow(line)
```

but this gives me an error about fieldnames.

I know this is a common question and I'm conscious that I'm only struggling because I really don't know what I'm doing- it has been a few years since I've used python and I've forgotten so much. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are passing a generator/sequence, use "writerows", not "writerow".  Pickle files are gibberish to people, but readable to Pickle, if you want to load somewhere else.  The arguments to DictWriter is: csvfile, fieldnames, ..., so your first argument is a file, your second is a list of field names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the reason for the main issue -

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

is that you are openning the file in binary mode, you should open the file in text mode ( without `b` ).

Secondly, I would say it would be easier to use normal [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) than [`csv.DictWriter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) in your case, because of the way your dictionary is created.

A way to write your result to csv would be -

```
#Assuming you have previously created the counter you want to write
#lets say you stored the counter in a variable called cnter
with open('newfile.csv','w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames=['number','colour','number2','count']
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    for key, value in cnter.items():
        writer.writerow(list(key) + [value])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import csv
```

Assuming *count* is a Python 3 Counter.
If *key* is a string, to not split it in every character it contains :

```
with open(root+'counter_test.csv','w') as csvfile:
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
    for key, value in count.items():
        writer.writerow([key] + [value])
```

And even simpler (take care of the 's' to writerows() function) :

```
with open(root+'counter_test.csv','w') as csvfile:
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(count.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

for me the above solution did not work. It splitted all the characters  of the word in separate columns so the output was "every character in a separate column followed by the count" rather than entire word in one column followed by count. It might have been due to some other errors that i might have made.
However for me the below code worked ::

```
    with open(outfile, encoding='utf-8-sig', mode='w') as fp:
        fp.write('KMC,freq\n')  
        for tag, count in cnt.items():  
            fp.write('{},{}\n'.format(tag, count))
```

I hope this is helpful for others

Comment: Yes. Thanks for sharing this alternative. I was also encountering a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using [pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

you can use this simple one liner :

```py
pd.DataFrame(Counter(my_list).most_common(), columns=["item", "count"]).to_csv("./myfile.csv")
```

Pandas can create a `DataFrame` from a dictionary (and a `Counter`), you have to specify the names of the columns for the DataFrame in the constructor (hence the `columns=["item", "count"]`)

Then, the DataFrame class has a simple `to_csv()` method (you may wish to use `index=False` when calling this method)

Answer (score 0):

Simply by using for loop we can add sequence counter to the CSV reade
following code will desplay the counter to the csv file

```
import csv

x=0
reader = csv.reader(open("c:/path/abc.csv"))
for raw in reader:
    x += 1
    print(raw)
    print(x)
```

above code will desplay output like this

['id', 'fname', 'lname']
1
['1', 'a', 'x']
2
['2', 'b', 'y']
3
['3', 'c', 'z']
4